# Delete extra columns of table before exporting to Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that runs a few API request and then export information on the test into an excel.

When I create the table to I adds couple column for the results. However when I export the tables via Excel there are a bunch of extra column I don't want.

```cs
$ResultsTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "ResultsTable"

$RTC1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Type",([string])
$RTC2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Endpoint",([string])
$RTC3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "PassRate",([string])
$RTC4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "AvgTime",([string])
$RTC5 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "MaxTime",([string])
$RTC6 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "AvgSize",([string])
$RTC7 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "MaxSize",([string])

$ResultsTable.Columns.Add($RTC1)
$ResultsTable.Columns.Add($RTC2)
$ResultsTable.Columns.Add($RTC3)
$ResultsTable.Columns.Add($RTC4)
$ResultsTable.Columns.Add($RTC5)
$ResultsTable.Columns.Add($RTC6)
$ResultsTable.Columns.Add($RTC7)

$Row = $ResultsTable.NewRow()
$Row.Type = "Direct"
$Row.Endpoint = $Uri
$Row.PassRate = "$PassRate%"
$Row.AvgTime = $AvgTime
$Row.MaxTime = $MaxTime
$Row.AvgSize = $AvgSize
$Row.MaxTime = $MaxSize
$ResultsTable.Rows.Add($Row)

$ResultsTable | Export-Excel -Path ".\Output\Unit\API.Customer.Unit.Tests - $DateTime.xlsx" `
    -AutoSize `
    -WorksheetName "Results" `
    -Title "Results Table" `
    -TitleBold `
    -BoldTopRow `
    -FreezeTopRow
```

The output of this export looks like:

[image]

I only need the Columns A - G. How do I get rid of the other columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either select the columns you want to keep:

```
$ResultsTable |
    Select-Object Type, Endpoint, PassRate, AvgTime, MaxTime, AvgSize, MaxSize |
    Export-Excel ...
```

or remove the columns you don't want to keep:

```
$ResultsTable |
    Select-Object -Property * -Exclude RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors |
    Export-Excel ...
```

---

If you know that you're always going to need exactly the columns defined in the table, you could also reference them directly:

```
$ResultsTable |
    Select-Object -Property $ResultsTable.Columns.ColumnName |
    Export-Excel ...
```

Comment: Sorry Ansgar, I didn't see you already posted an answer before I did mine. I'll remove my answer since it is the same as your second option.

Comment: @Theo Don't worry about it. The UI has some latency, so these things happen from time to time.

Comment: Perfect Thank you very much

Comment: Why not `$ResultsTable |Select-Object $ResultsTable.Columns.ColumnName | ...`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Because of my general lack of familiarity with the intricate details of data tables? ;)

Comment: Fair enough, hehe ^_^